# TensorFlow: How to make learning rate in Gradient Descent decrease over time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

When declaring gradient descent, I apparently have to define the train step prior to initialization:

```
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(eta).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)
...
```

How do I adjust eta as I increase the number of epochs I learn?

Comment: You mean you want an adaptive gradient descent. But what happens if the gradient spikes, and the step drops to zero what do we do then? In any case you want to use a small step size and monitor the evolution of the error.

Comment: check out the way it's done in official mnist example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/12f279d6f4cb33574bc20109b41eb8a59f40cfd1/tutorials/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L243)

Comment: @Chinny84 just want to slow down and be careful when the learner jumps up rapidly in accuracy, so I don't lose the peak.